# emacs - loading compile done error

Tags: emacs

In emacs - every now and then I'm running a command I don't want (don't know which one) and the status bar says `"Loading compile...done"` and emacs doesn't respond. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to start emacs via `emacs -Q`. If the error still persists, you need to debug yourself. If you cannot debug, you should send an email to GNU emacs-devel lists.

If the error dissapears, that means you have a bad `.emacs` or `startup.el`.